# Getting the right output from lm script in R

Tags: r, lm

I am trying to calculate Beta's and standard errors for 50+ SNPs and their individual effect on age at menopause. My script isn't quite right. I want to use `country` as a co-variate and do a linear regression of age of menopause (`a_menopause`) and each individual SNP.

When I do the calculation SNP by SNP, I get the right answers. This is the command I use:

```
rs <- lm(a_menopause~rs17465637_metabo + country, data="x")
summary(rs)
```

The output looks like this (I am only interested in the second row (rs) and specifically the estimate and std. error:

```
Coefficients:
                      Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)          49.515274   0.340216 145.541   <2e-16 ***
rs                   -0.004258   0.171557  -0.025    0.980    
RS$country            0.019684   0.047994   0.410    0.682
```

I now have the following script to try and replace the rs17465637_metabo by a new variable each time. However when I look at my output, all the values are very similar (and very different from when I do it one SNP at a time). I also only get the (intercept) value and not the RS values.

This is my script:

```
read.data <- function(file="RS.csv") {
  x <- read.csv(file, sep=";", dec=",") 
  x$country <- factor(x$country)        
  x
}

## Fit the LMs
fit.lms <- function(x) {
  rsid <- colnames(x)[-(1:3)]         # all column names except the first three
  res <- vector("list", length=length(rsid))
  i <- 1
  for (rs in rsid) {
    modeltxt <- paste("lm(a_menopause ~ 0 + ", rsid, " + country, data=x)") # build model expression text
    r <- eval(parse(text=modeltxt)) 
    s <- summary(r)$coefficients    
    res[[i]] <- c(s[2,], s[2,])     
    i <- i+1
  }
  data.frame(do.call(rbind, res), rsid=rsid)
}

run <- function() {
  x <- read.data()
  lms <- fit.lms(x)
  write.table(lms, file="fits.csv", sep=";", dec=",", row.names=F)
}
```

Where am I going wrong? How do I change the output to give me the second row of data?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is hard to understand anything from your code, because you didn't provide an example of your data, and even lm call is hidden inside `eval()` statement. I guess you should look at the names of your linear model object. If you generated it like `rs <- lm(a_menopause~rs17465637_metabo + country, data="x") summary(rs)`, `names(rs)` should give you clues about which data is stored where

Comment: use the function `as.formula` to create your model formulas dynamically so as to avoid having to use the `parse` `eval` construct.

Comment: And you're pasting rsid into modeltxt, creating a long vector instead of one string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't `use eval(parse())` but `as.formula(paste())`

```
my.form <- as.formula(paste("a_menopause ~ 0 +", rs, "+ country")))
r <- lm(my.form, data=x)
```

Here is how you can extract the second row.

```
output <- lapply(rsid, function(rs){
    my.form <- as.formula(paste("a_menopause ~ 0 +", rs, "+ country")))
    r <- lm(my.form, data=x)
    summary(r)$coefficients[2, c("Estimate", "Std. Error")]
})
do.call(rbind, output)
```

Note that this is untested since you failed to provide sample data